# How to compare one file's data to other file's data using python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 90 files in csv format which have data like this-

```
    PID,          STARTED,%CPU,%MEM,COMMAND
    1,Wed Sep 12 10:10:21 2018, 0.0, 0.0,init
    2,Wed Sep 12 10:10:21 2018, 0.0, 0.0,kthreadd
```

Now I have to compare in such a way that whether file2 has any repeting data(PID,STARTED,%CPU,%MEM,COMMAND)with file1 or not.
If file2 has repeated data then pick the repeated data with all values(PID,COMMAND,STARTED,%CPU,%MEM) and store it in a seperate files. 
Same explained process I have to do with all 90 files. 
My code(Approach) is here. Please have a look -

```
file=open(r"Latest_27_02_2019.csv","r")
pidList=[]
pNameList=[]
memList=[]
startTimeList=[]
df=pd.read_csv(file)
pidList=df.index
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
pidList = df['PID']
pNameList=df['COMMAND']
memList=df['%MEM']
startTimeList=df['STARTED']
After that compare one by one.
```

But since I have large number files. So it will take more time and more iteration. 
Somehow I have found that it can be do in easier way with help of python(pandas library) but don't know how? Please help me?

Comment: your file1 is the main file and all others have to compare their datas with it?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution for comparing 2 files:

```
#read file1 to df1
#your header seems no good with blank, so i rename it
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1',  sep=',' header=1, names=['PID','STARTED','%CPU','%MEM','COMMAND']])
#df1 is your first file, df2 the second
df_compare = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(), on=['PID','STARTED','%CPU','%MEM','COMMAND'],
                   how='right', indicator=True)

print(df_compare)

#in result, you'll have a column '_merge' with both or right_only
#right_only means only in df2 and not in df1
#after you just filtered:

filter = df_compare._merge == 'both'
df_compare = df_compare[filter].drop(['_merge'],axis=1)

#in df_compare, you have the repeateted rows from df2 and df1, you could reindex if you want
print(df_compare)
```

or another solution (better i think):

```
df_compare = df1[df1.index.isin(df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on=['PID','STARTED','%CPU','%MEM','COMMAND']).index)]
print(df_compare)
```

Comment: Sir, I have imported pandas library but df_all showing unresolved reference.

Comment: It's working. Sir could you pls help me to know that How I can load file3 in the data frame automatically(means I am thinking to give the file location and I want that it will pick next file(say file3, file4, file5.......file90 automatically)) and how to compare file3's data with "df_compare's" data.

Comment: ok file2, file 3 and file4 to compare at file1? and all repeated row in df?

Comment: No sir, now the need is to compare file3, file4, file 5....................file90 with stored data in df_compare(i.e final output of file1 and file2).

Comment: i am lost, df_compare contain the rows which are in file1 and file2, and i dont understand why you compare this result with all other files,

Comment: Ok sir. So, the purpose is like this - first I will compare all files and will find which PID is available in most of the files, then I'll report it.

Comment: the question changes, so here you have all coding to compare 2 files, now you want to find PID available in most of the files, its another job so i suggest you to ask another question to avoid to pollute this.

Comment: Thank you sir. Anyway I have found my solution.